# Как реализовать проверку параметров метода на соответствие определенному типу?

Tags: c#, исключения

Как можно реализовать проверку параметров на строгое соответствие определенному типу?
Нужно чтобы метод не пытался неявно привести тип аргумента к указанному типу, а в случае не соответствия сразу кидал Exception. Например при передаче b параметра типа char, нужно, чтобы он не брал его код, а сразу кидал Ex.
Код некорректный, просто для примера

```
        public static string task01 (int a, double b)
    {
        if ((typeof(double) != b.GetType())) throw new ArgumentException($"Параметр {b} не является вещественным числом");
        if ((typeof(int) != a.GetType())) throw new ArgumentException($"Параметр {a} не является целым числом");

        string s1 = ("привет, " + a + '!' + '\n' + a + " + " + b + " = " + (a + b) + '\n' + "пока, " + b + "...");
        return s1;
    }
```

Comment: Проверить через `is`? `if (a is int) { //a у нас int, преобразуем сами если надо, или делаем что-то др. }`, дальше уже комбинируйте и делайте что хотите, например `if (a is int intA) { //intA у нас уже преобразован в нужный тип }`, или `if (a is not int or string)`, короче, возможностей много, пользуйтесь)

Comment: Чисто теоретически можно попробовать написать анализатор кода на Roslyn (это будет работать во время компиляции, а не в рантайме). Но стоит ли игра свеч?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых, проверка типов параметров - это работа компилятора, а не ваша. Если переданный параметр никак не привести к типу параметра в функции, то у вас код просто не скомпилируется.

Во вторых, в вашем примере, типы параметров будут конвертированы неявно до вызова метода - просто вызовите `Console.WriteLine(task01('1', '2'));` и увидите, что char, что вы передали, будет преобразован в int и double до вызова метода и внутри метода уже будут параметры типа int и double.

В третьих, если вам надо такую проверку писать для своих классов, тогда у вас вероятно проблемы с буквой L из SOLID.